# Debugger error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to write some code to draw an empty textured room on Android, using a library built on the libgdx framework. The library contains some objects definition and in particular a textured cuboid that I'm using.

This is my create method:

```
public void create() {

    // create new perspective camera with FOV = 67
    _camera = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    _camera.translate(0, 0, 10);
    _camera.lookAt(new Vector3(0,0,1));
    _camera.near = 0.1f;
    _camera.far = 100f;


    // load texture for box
    _texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/checker.jpg"));

    // create box
    _box = new TexturedCuboid(new Vector3(0,0,10), new Quaternion(Vector3.Z, 0), new Vector3(10,10,10), _texture,new Vector2(1.0f,1.0f), true);

    // repeat texture
    _box.setTextureWrapMethod(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.Repeat);

    // apply linear filtering to texture
    _box.setTextureFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

    // create light vector
    _light = new Light(0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.2f, 1000.0f);

    // load shaders
    _shader = new ShaderProgram(Gdx.files.internal("shaders/simple.vert"), Gdx.files.internal("shaders/simple.frag"));

    }
```

I'm getting this error from the debugger when I try to execute the code:

```
1-17 15:33:01.445: E/AndroidRuntime(3386): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 285
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:nl.uu.MobileVRLib.meshes.TexturedCuboid.setVertices
```

This is the texturedCuboid constructor:

```
public TexturedCuboid(final Vector3 position, final Quaternion orientation, final Vector3 size, final Texture texture, final Vector2 textureSize, boolean boxMode) {
    // Call constructor.
    super(position, orientation, size, texture, true, 24, 36, textureSize, VertexAttribute.Position(), VertexAttribute.Normal(), VertexAttribute.TexCoords(0));

    // Set box mode.
    _boxMode = boxMode;

    // We can now create our vertices.
    createVerticesCustom();
}
```

And finally the code that raises the exception:

```
private void createVerticesCustom() {
 // Assign the vertices locations, normals and the texture coordinates u v.
    setVertices(new float[] {
        // Front
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0, (_boxMode ? -1 : 1), 0, 0,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0, (_boxMode ? -1 : 1), 0, 1, 
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0, 1, (_boxMode ? -1 : 1), 0, 
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0, 1, (_boxMode ? -1 : 1), 1,

        // Back
        0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0, (_boxMode ? 1 : -1), 0, 0,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0, (_boxMode ? 1 : -1), 0, 1, 
        -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0, (_boxMode ? 1 : -1), 1, 0, 
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0, (_boxMode ? 1 : -1), 1, 1,

        // Top
        -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0, (_boxMode ? -1 : 1), 0, 0, 0,
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0, (_boxMode ? -1 : 1), 0, 0, 1, 
        0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0, (_boxMode ? -1 : 1), 0, 1, 0, 
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0, (_boxMode ? -1 : 1), 0, 1, 1,

        // Bottom
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0, (_boxMode ? 1 : -1), 0, 0, 0,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, (_boxMode ? 1 : -1), 0, 0, 1, 
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0, (_boxMode ? 1 : -1), 0, 1, 0, 
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, (_boxMode ? 1 : -1), 0, 1, 1,

        // Left
        -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, (_boxMode ? 1 : -1), 0, 0, 0, 0,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, (_boxMode ? 1 : -1), 0, 0, 0, 1, 
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, (_boxMode ? 1 : -1), 0, 0, 1, 0,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, (_boxMode ? 1 : -1), 0, 0, 1, 1,

        // Right
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, (_boxMode ? -1 : 1), 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, (_boxMode ? -1 : 1), 0, 0, 0, 1, 
        0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, (_boxMode ? -1 : 1), 0, 0, 1, 0, 
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, (_boxMode ? -1 : 1), 0, 0, 1, 1
    });

    if (_boxMode) {
        setIndices(new short[] {
                // front
                2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 0,
                // back
                6, 7, 5, 6, 5, 4,
                // top
                10, 11, 9, 10, 9, 8,
                // bottom
                12, 13, 14, 13, 15, 14,
                // left
                18, 19, 17, 18, 17, 16,
                // right
                22, 23, 21, 22, 21, 20 });
    }
    else {
        setIndices(new short[] {
                // front
                0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2,
                // back
                4, 5, 6, 5, 7, 6,
                // top
                8, 9, 10, 9, 11, 10,
                // bottom
                14, 15, 13, 14, 13, 12,
                // left
                16, 17, 18, 17, 19, 18,
                // right
                20, 21, 22, 21, 23, 22 });

    }

}
```

}

I can't figure out why the exception is raised. Any ideas? I am sure that the library is working because it's been successfully used in another project.

Comment: Is there such a method with that precise signature in the version of the library you're using and deploying?

Comment: The setVertices method is a method of libgdx's Mesh class (http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Mesh.html), which is the base class of the texturedCuboid, so I'm sure it is there.

Comment: What's the entire error, *including the signature*?

Comment: Please post TextureCuboid class definition.

Comment: I ended up just copying some of the classes that I needed from the library, but the guy who built the library confirmed to me that it's quite buggy. Thanks anyways